# Logout on ServiceStack v4

Tags: servicestack

I have ServiceStack v4 service but when I call the `auth/logout` route (using either `POST` or `GET`) to logout the currently logged-in user, I get an error:

> 400 Not Empty
>     User Name cannot be empty
>     Password Cannot be empty

As I wouldn't expect users to enter credentials when logging out, I am surely missing something?

I have the `AuthFeature` registered during host initialisation, and I am using `CredentialsAuthProvider`. I have taken the code from Github so I can see how it works.

My Client Code:

```js
var rest = Restangular.one('auth/logout').get(); 
//var result = rest.post({userName: userName}); 
this.requestTracker.addPromise(rest); 
return rest;
```

Comment: So you have tried `client.Post(new Authenticate { provider = AuthenticateService.LogoutAction });`?

Comment: Can you paste your code, so I can see if I can reproduce this?

Comment: Hi, I am calling this from an angular app (via restangular), so am not using the SS client libraries.  I have the AuthFeature registered during host initialisation, and I am using CredentialsAuthProvider (I have taken the code from github so I can see how it works).

        var rest = Restangular.one('auth/logout').get();
        //var result = rest.post({userName: userName});
        this.requestTracker.addPromise(rest);
        return rest;

Tried this with a post as well.

Comment: Reasonably new to ServiceStack, so forgive me if this isn't right, but...  

In CredentialsAuthProvider.cs, there is an abstract validator for the Authenticate request, which checks for username and password being empty.

In AuthenticateService.cs, the Logout logic is on line 112, but the request for this method is of type Authenticate, which will inevitably fire the validator.  Is this the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging, this happens when you are using CredentialsAuthProvider.  Within this class, a validator is defined that validates all instances of the Authenticate request.  As the logout route uses the Authenticate request, this validator is fired.

I got round it by modifying the validator to:

```
RuleFor(x => x.UserName).NotEmpty().When(d => d.provider != "logout");
RuleFor(x => x.Password).NotEmpty().When(d => d.provider != "logout");
```

This is probably not the most elegant way of fixing long term, but got me up and running.

Comment: Weird. Maybe you should fill a bug reporting this.

Comment: Where should i do that - github?

Comment: I can't repro this, it would help if you provided either the source code or the HTTP Request/Response so we can see what's actually going on? I've [added this test to try repro the issue](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/089195c8af0bd4c0736a07466766fd5530be1053) but it passes, if you provide the source code that's causing the issue we can help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I recently have been struggling with the same thing. What occurs is that before the Authenticate.Post function is called, the validation cache is checked and the CredentialsAuthProvider which has the mentioned validator fails unless username and password are not empty.

Now, i'm not sure if it makes a difference if you only have that provider enabled or not - I've not tested. I actually have my own custom provider that subclasses CredentialsAuthProvider and it's the only one I register.

The only way currently is to either pass a non-empty (but useless) password and username, or modify your own custom provider, overriding the Authenticate function and using a modified version of the validator as mentioned above.